# jquery selector: selecting all elements next to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here's my markup:

```
<ul>
    <li class='product'></li>
    <li id='foo' class='product'></li>
    <li class='insert'></li>
    <li class='insert'></li>
    <li class='product'></li>
    <li class='product'></li>
    <li class='product'></li>
</ul>
```

starting from li#foo, i want to append another `li.insert` element after the LAST .insert element - i guess i need to select all neighbour elements  from #foo having class insert then append a new item..
any ideas?

desired output:

```
<ul>
    <li class='product'></li>
    <li id=foo class='product'></li>
    <li class='insert'></li>
    <li class='insert'></li>
    <li class='insert'>new item</li>
    <li class='product'></li>
    <li class='product'></li>
    <li class='product'></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why quotes is not there <li id=foo ?

Comment: `$('.product').click(function(){$(this.nextAll();)})`

Answer (score 4):

Use **[`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** pseudo-class selector to get the last element and insert the `li` by using **[`after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/)** method in jQuery.

```js
// get the last `li` with the class
$('ul li.insert:last')
  // append the html string after the element
  .after('<li class="select">New Item</li>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='product'></li>
  <li id=foo class='product'></li>
  <li class='insert'></li>
  <li class='insert'></li>
  <li class='product'></li>
  <li class='product'></li>
  <li class='product'></li>
</ul>
```

---

If you are generating element with jQuery then **[`insertAfter()`](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)** method can be used.

```js
// generate li with the content
$('<li/>', {
  class: 'select',
  text: 'New Item'
    // insert after the last li with specific class  
}).insertAfter('ul li.insert:last')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='product'></li>
  <li id=foo class='product'></li>
  <li class='insert'></li>
  <li class='insert'></li>
  <li class='product'></li>
  <li class='product'></li>
  <li class='product'></li>
</ul>
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you only want to consider the element after the `#foo` element then use **[`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)** method.

```js
// get the `li` with the id
$('#foo')
  // get the last `li` after it with a certain class 
  .nextAll('.insert:last')
  // append the html string after the element
  .after('<li class="select">New Item</li>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='product'></li>
  <li id=foo class='product'></li>
  <li class='insert'></li>
  <li class='insert'></li>
  <li class='product'></li>
  <li class='product'></li>
  <li class='product'></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to depend on `#foo` then use siblings to catch the `<li>` on the same level of `#foo` and the use `:last` pseudo class to insert element after last `<li>`

```js
$('#foo').siblings('.insert:last').after('<li class="insert">New Item</li>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='product'></li>
  <li id=foo class='product'></li>
  <li class='insert'></li>
  <li class='insert'></li>
  <li class='product'></li>
  <li class='product'></li>
  <li class='product'></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('li.insert:last-child').after('<li class="insert">new item</li>');
```

Comment: It will append inside `li.insert:last-child`

Comment: This answer is already given. Try to give some different way of answer, it will help to viewers.

Comment: Instead of after, unknowingly typed append.. so I have edited as soon as seen the comment @Mani

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.